# Copy users folder to new folder using nested foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach, robocopy

I am trying to copy c:\users folder to new destination with `robocopy`. Something is wrong here with my nested `foreach` statement:

```
$users = @(
    'jack'
    'Jon'
)
$news = @(
    'jacknew'
    'JonNew'
)

foreach ($userx in $users) {
    foreach ($new in $news) {
        $source = "c:\users\$($userx)"
        $destination = "d:\users\$($new)"

        robocopy $source $destination /MIR /LOG:c:\robocopy.txt /NP
    }
}
```

It copies both the folders to d:\jacknew folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `foreach` loops, so you will execute `robocopy` 4 times:

```
robocopy c:\users\jack d:\users\jacknew /MIR /LOG:c:\robocopy.txt /NP
robocopy c:\users\jack d:\users\jonnew /MIR /LOG:c:\robocopy.txt /NP
robocopy c:\users\Jon d:\users\jacknew /MIR /LOG:c:\robocopy.txt /NP
robocopy c:\users\Jon d:\users\jonnew /MIR /LOG:c:\robocopy.txt /NP
```

If you want to copy `jack` and `jon` to corresponding folders `jacknew` and `jonnew`, you can use a single `foreach` loop and simply append the `new` when you copy; e.g.:

```
    $users = @(
    'jack'
    'Jon'
    )
    foreach ( $user in $users ) {
      $source = "c:\users\$($user)"
      $destination = "d:\users\$($user)new"
      robocopy $source $destination /MIR /LOG:c:\robocopy.txt /NP
    }
```

Comment: As a side note: use a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) for mapping source to destination folders if the destination folders can't be constructed by simply appending a string.